# Unexpected result from Oracle SDO_AGGR_UNION

Tags: buffer, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I'm getting a result that looks incorrect from the Oracle Spatial SDO_AGGR_UNION function.  I'm hoping someone has seen this and can confirm it's a bug or explain why this is expected behavior.  Following the example C-5 in the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_complex_queries.htm#SPATL1285) I wrote the following statement to buffer and union a set of polygons:

```
    select SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS from 
        (select SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS from
            (select SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS from 
                (select SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS from
                        (
                        select 
                        SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(SUBQRY.BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS
                        from
                                (
                                select SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER(MDSYS.SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SF_PROJ.SHAPE,0.005,1000105),500,0.001)
                                as BUFFS
                                from SF_PROJ
                                left outer join SF
                                on SF_PROJ.SF_ID = SF.SF_ID
                                where SF.ES_ID = 'A'
                                ) SUBQRY
                group by mod (rownum, 128))
            group by mod (rownum, 32))
        group by mod (rownum, 8))
    group by mod (rownum, 2));
```

The result looks as expected except for one area where it looks like the areas of overlap between several polys has been clipped out of the result.  The multi colored picture shows the un-aggregated buffers.[image: These are the buffers in the initial selection]

The next image (blue) shows the result that was a problem.
[image: Unexpected (problem) result]

I was able to get the expected result, (shown below in green) by removing the first two levels of nested aggregation as follows but I'd like to be able to figure why this happened so I can prevent it for use with larger numbers of polygons for which I understand that the extra levels of nesting will be necessary for decent performance.  The group in this example contains 790 features to be buffered and aggregated but other groups contain several thousand.  How can this behavior be explained?

Script that produces expected result:

```
    select SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS from 
        (select SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS from
                        (
                        select 
                        SDO_AGGR_UNION(SDOAGGRTYPE(SUBQRY.BUFFS, 0.001)) as BUFFS
                        from
                                (
                                select SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER(MDSYS.SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SF_PROJ.SHAPE,0.005,1000105),500,0.001)
                                as BUFFS
                                from SF_PROJ
                                left outer join SF
                                on SF_PROJ.SF_ID = SF.SF_ID
                                where SF.ES_ID = 'A'
                                ) SUBQRY
        group by mod (rownum, 8))
    group by mod (rownum, 2));
```

This is the expected result:

[image: Expected (correct) result]

Comment: You might need to repair one or more of your geometries -- Inverse holes often occur when the polygon is not wrapped in the right direction.

Comment: I was just thinking about that.  I did run sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context on all of the starting features and there were just three with 13356 (adjacent points in a geometry are redundant).  I thought maybe the buffer could create invalid geometries and so I inserted a sdo_util.rectify_geometry after the buffer step but still got the bad result.  Can you think of any other way the rings could end up oriented incorrectly during the process?

Comment: It could be a buggy algorithm, but that would be off-topic here.

Comment: can you generate a small sample of the polygons that demonstrates the issue and add them to the question?

Comment: I think I got it.  It looks like the problem was that the tolerance of the starting shapes was 0.01 and I was specifying a smaller tolerance (0.005 or 0.001) for the other operations.  My guess is that the mixture of tolerances resulted in geometries that were invalid at some stage.  Sound plausible?

Comment: Yes, tolerance is important for aggregations (as well as other geometry transformations). What exact version of the database do you use ? Did you enable spatial vector acceleration ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the pointers! I'm using Oracle 12c.  I did not enable spatial vector accel and don't even have permissions to see the system setting.  I'm asking our dba if it's enabled.  It looks like I can just enable it for the session so maybe I'll try that.